# Getting QGIS go2streetview view to stay in locked browser window

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

In QGIS the go2streetview Plugin is there ready to go.  The icon displays and the window asks you to click on map and drag cursor to display Google Street View. When this is carried out nothing happens though in the browser window that is locked in.

However, if I click on the map and drag the cursor whilst holding down the control key, it works but opens up in a new browser window.

How do I get the view to stay in the locked browser window?
[image]

Comment: running into the same problem. upgraded QGIS from Essen to Las Palmas(2.18) and all the sudden lost my windowed view, but you're right, holding control helps in the meantime.

Comment: Try to install QGIS 3.2. Madeira. Also, I had this problem yesterday and now It's ok. I hope.

Comment: I got the same problem in version 2.18. First noticed 12/11/2018. Works in version 3, but that doesn't help. I need to use it in version 2.18